# Azure Stream Analytics Tool for Visual Studio in 2019 preview

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics, visual-studio-2019

I am just creating an Azure Stream Analytics using [Azure Stream Analytics Tool for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-quick-create-vs) in 2019 preview version, but it is saying that the version of Visual Studio is not supported. I am sure that I have installed the required workloads and extensions.

[image]

I am also sure that I have connected to my Azure Subscription using the Server Explorer.

[image]

Any idea why? Is it really not supported yet or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like the extensions are not supported in the new Visual Studio yet. But it is not a blocker, we can still use the option "Provide data source settings manually" and complete the configuration.

[image]

Note: After configuring the Input, Output, Query when I try to Submit to Azure, the Visual Studio is getting closed. It seems like it is a bug.

You can also consider using Visual Studio 2017 till the new release of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

We do not support Visual studio 2019 currently and will figure out how to adapt to the latest vs version. 
Keep using VS2107 should be a better choice